# Why do I have so many problems refreshing code in Android emulator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, emulation

So I have just started learning app development with React Native this past week and so I've been getting into using Android studio emulators to run my apps. I've noticed that when I run the apps on the emulator, it doesn't seem to refresh the code properly. For example I made this very simple app while following a tutorial:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'native-base';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Testing 12321</Text>
        <Button><text>Hello World!</text></Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 24
  }
}
```

But when I first created it, in the tutorial the instructor forgot to put the Text tag within the button, so when I ran the app I got an error of:

```
Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4137:14 in <anonymous>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4134:2 in createTextInstance
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15909:12 in completeWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19409:28 in completeUnitOfWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19380:30 in performUnitOfWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
* [native code]:null in renderRoot
```

and it keeps going. Then in the tutorial the instructor noticed the mistake and fixed it by adding the  tag in the button, but then when he does that, the app refreshed properly and displayed the button but for me I still get this same error. I've noticed this happening quite often with the Emulator, it doesnt like to refresh properly when opening a new app or altering one. I have deleted and recreated the emulator like 5 or more times now to test out different apps. Does anyone have a suggestion of how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `<text>` to `<Text>` as below.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <Text>Testing 12321</Text>
   <Button><Text>Hello World!</Text></Button>
</View>
```

Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the errors but now the screen is just blank in the emulator, not sure if something is messed up with the layout, I'll have to play around a bit to try and figure it out, do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: not yet, its a very simple app and it was working before the error so tomorrow afternoon I think I'll just start from the beginning and make sure I write the tag as <Text> and hopefully that will work